# Connect multiple database mysqli with different users and passwords

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have 2 databases (db1,db2)in mysqli with different users and passwords,
I try to connect but it failed ,

```
$this->db = mysqli_connect(self::DB_SERVER, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD,self::DB);
```

I did in the query:

```
select*from db2.table
```

but gave an error ,
the example above success in local when there is no user and password for databases. Please help

Comment: It fails the connection or the query? If fails the connection, maybe there are a limit in server config.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Answer (score -1):

If you have different usernames and passwords on the databases, I don't think a single connection can go across that. So you would at the very least have to change them to use the same mysql user.

OR, if you don't need to access from a single connection use something like this:

https://github.com/thephpeffect/ConnectionManager

```
db("default", new mysqli(self::DB_SERVER, self::DB_USER1, self::DB_PASSWORD1,self::DB1));
db("db2", new mysqli(self::DB_SERVER, self::DB_USER2, self::DB_PASSWORD2,self::DB2));

$result = db("db2")->query("select*from db2.table");
```

Comment: different usernames and passwords on  databases and not tables

Comment: I freudian slipped, I meant to say databases, and not tables (it's been edited)

To reiterate, you cannot query across databases with different users if they don't have access. Ie. If user1 has access on db1 but not db2, then user1 cannot query from a connection to db1 and select data on db2. So, if you want to be able to access it, you need to two separate connections open.

And thus my answer still holds.